# How do I structure code properly in Python?

Tags: python, operating-system, setup.py, pep8

I have a python setup.py file which installs a certain homebrew package, php and other dependencies for my project.
I have total of 5 installations which are written in 5 different functions.This is how the code looks now

```
<code>
import standard libs such as os,shlex etc.
def a:
    "Some code here with try except clauses"

def b:
    "Some code here with try except clauses"

3 more such functions

if "__name__" =="__main__":
   a()
   b()
   c()
</code>
```

I am planning to send a pull request of the above code so that the users of that open source code can download the setup.file and execute it.

I am wondering if this is the best way to write the script?Can somebody throw some light , docs regarding the pythonic way to make the code more elegant before I face a thorough code review?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html) as it is easy to understand and follow, and it includes reasoning for each point.

Another, more standard one you can follow is the [PEP8 Python Style Guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which will be pretty similar to the Google one, but following it is industry standard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you simplified the code?

It looks good to me, however if you really wanted to get fancy, you could have another function named `run()` which just runs `a()`, `b()` and `c()`.

Also don't have quotes around `__name__`, for it is a built-in variable.

Make sure to add `()` parentheses after each function, e.g: `def a:` will be `def a():`.

I hope this helps.

-Coolq.

Comment: Yeah. the quotes were actully a typo...I the code runs perfectly fine though.

Comment: Ok, good to know.